# Adding SweetAlert2 to update.js.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm stuck in developing my rails application - I'm relatively new to Rails and trying to get comfortable with javascript.
So, I just added SweetAlert2 via Webpacker and it's working fine. 
I have a form which I am submitting via Javascript, which is also working.

Here is my controller action:

```
def update
    @user = @card.user
    day = Date.today
    if @card.update(card_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {}
    end
  end
end
```

So when this is executed and the form is submitted, I'm calling a JS-function from an index.js-file which I imported in application.js.

Index.js:

```
import swal from 'sweetalert2'
import Rails from '@rails/ujs'

$(function() {
    $('#vollkostForm').submit(function(){
            swal.fire({
                title: "Bestellung abgeschlossen!",
                text: "Die Mahlzeit wurde erfolgreich bestellt",
                type: "success"
            });
        $('#vollkostModal').modal('hide');
    });
});
```

This is working correctly, the alert is showing up.
But what I would like to achieve (since this should only run if the form was successfully submitted), is that this function is in the corresponding update.js.erb file, which belongs to the `format.js {}` block.

I tried everything but I can't figure out how to import this SweetAlert library to the update.js.erb.

I'm always getting the error message "swal is not defined" - if I just use something like alert("Hello!"), this is working fine.

I just can't use or import third-party plugins to work aswell.

Thanks for any advice! :)

Answer (score 0):

What page is your form on? Is it on the index page? If so, then your JavaScript code will need to be in `index.js` and not `update.js`. You can't have your JavaScript code check if the form has been submitted AFTER the form has already been submitted.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Hey, the Index.js is just a file where my other code for SweetAlert etc. goes. It' in the Javascript/packs directory, so not related to my action. The name is kind of misleading, sorry. In the update.js.erb i Just want to call the swal.fire method, nur then it tells me swal is not defined. If I try to Import it like I did in the Index.js it doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: As I said: The problem is not that NO Code in update.js.erb is executed - alerts for example do work. Just third party libraries where I need imports don't

Answer (score 0):

You may make one function and keep it in common file like application.js and call that function whenever you need. So, you don't require to import sweetalert2 everywhere.

```
function popupSweetAlert(title, text, type) {
  swal.fire({
    title: title,
    text: text,
    type: type
  });
}
```

I hope, this is helpful for you.